# javax.persistence.version causes the Id of an entity to remain null in the transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, optimistic-locking

I have two entities with typical primary foreign key relationship. id in EntityA is has foreign key relationship in EntityB. I am trying to persist entity A and entity B in same transaction.

```
Entity A
-------------------------------
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Version
private Integer version;

Entity B
--------------------------------
@ManyToOne
@JsonBackReference
@JoinColumn(name = "id_fk")
private EntityA entityA;

@Version
private Integer version;
```

I am using `javax.persistence.version` annotation to perform the optimistic locking on version column. I have two statements

```
   1. entityARepository.save(entityA)
   2. EntityB entityB = generateEntityB(entityA)
   3. entityBRepository.save(entityB)
```

The statement number 3 fails with exception that entity A id is null and entityB can not be saved with id null of entity A. I tried to use `entityManager.flush()` after statement 1 but the id of entity A is not getting generated when line 3 is encountered.

How to change the code so that Id of entity A gets generated and persisted so that when entityB tries to get that primary key of entity A it is not `null`?

Comment: If you are saving 2 entities then kindly POST the entities (JPA is orientated around CLASSES, not TABLES), and the code to interrelate the objects, and then post the actual SQL invoked

Comment: see the updated question. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using JPA? then you  use an Entitymanager, I presume.  The save-method does  a call to entitymanager.persist? I deleted my first question

Comment: I am using CrudRepository of spring data so save is same as persist. I found the problem I needed to get the new object that gets returned from line 1 and then save it in line 2. Apparently save operation changes the entity instance.

Comment: a works as entitymanager.merge. ok

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is having the same issue the save operation of `CrudRepository` of `Spring Data` may return entirely different instance of entity so you will have to do following.

```
   1. entityA = entityARepository.save(entityA)
   2. EntityB entityB = generateEntityB(entityA)
   3. entityBRepository.save(entityB)
```